# Is it possible to change a view from a user view to a node view?

Tags: 6, views

I have a view that has a couple of displays and a lot of complex field definitions. I now realize the view may have been created by cloning the wrong starter view. Something went wrong such that the view is based on user and the base_table = 'user' when it should be based on nodes. Can I change it to be based on nodes? Or is there a quick way to add my display and field definitions to a newly created node view, perhaps by exporting both and copying over bits of the code? I'm using Views 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to convert a user view to a node view or vice versa.

Although you probably could get away with manually combining the fields from the export of your user view with a plain export of a new node view, it would be faster and a lot less problematic to just open the old view and your new view side by side in two browser windows and recreate everything.

Unfortunately a lot of Drupal site building is just checking checkboxes...